# How do I return an array from html to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list containing items in an html tag. The list looks something like this:

```
['pizza', 'pasta', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pasta']
```

This is shown in my webpage through the following tag:

```
<p id='list'>['pizza', 'pasta', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pasta']</p>
```

Now I need this list to run some calculations in JavaScript. So I got the element in my JavaScript file by doing:

```
list = document.getElementById('list').innerHTML
```

The problem is that this returns a string. When asking for the type it is undefined...
If we would log

```
list[0]
```

This returns [.

What do I need to do to get the list as an array in JavaScript?

Comment: Fix the HTML so that it contains JSON instead, then parse the JSON

Comment: Or ideally, embed the data in the page in another way, rather than as text on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is exactly as shown and you can't change it to be valid JSON, you can use `replace` to replace the `'` with `"`, which will make it valid JSON. **But**, if there are any `\'` in the strings (you haven't shown any), they'll break, so this approach only works for the simple case:

```
var list = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('list').textContent.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

That will result in `list` being an array of strings.

---

Ideally, though, I'd suggest embedding the data in the page a different way or at least updating what's embedded to be valid JSON so we don't have to do the `replace` and thus worry about the `\'` possibility...

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you! I am indeed going to look for a different way to get the data, but at least it works for now... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If input remains in the same format then it can be parsed with regex.

Get the content of the tag.

```
let list = document.getElementById('list').innerHTML //"['pizza', 'pasta', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pasta']";
```

Replace the quotes and brackets.

```
list = list.replace(/[\]\[']/g,"");
```

And then split the string with `,`, it will return the array.

```
console.log(list.split(","));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'pizza', ' pasta', ' pizza', ' pizza', ' pasta' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy.

1) Grab your element with selector

```
var p = document.querySelector('#list');
```

2) Grab the innerHtml, you correctly found out that it's a string

```
var text = p.innerHTML;
```

3) The magic is that you can parse the string to JSON. However single quotes are not valid in JSON so tehy have to be replaced with double quotes

```
var ary = JSON.parse(p.replace(/\'/g, '\"'));
console.log(ary[0]) // => 'pizza'
```

Edit: If you do not want to replace the quotes to make it valid JSON you can use another built in method (however it is unsafe). Eval interprets anything passed as JavaScript itself so it is capable of running functions etc that makes it unsafe.

```
var g = eval("['4']");
console.log(g[0]); // => '4'
```

Comment: BTW, there's no reason for the backslashes in your `replace` call (either of them).

Answer (score -2):

```
const arr = "['pizza', 'pasta', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'pasta']";
console.log(JSON.parse(arr.replace(/\'/g, '\"')));
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check.

```js
var arraylist = document.getElementById('list').innerHTML;

console.log("arraylist:", arraylist);

var ary = JSON.parse(arraylist);

console.log("FIRST VALUE:", ary[0]);
```

```html
<p id='list'>["service1", "service2", "service3"]</p>
```

Comment: Put explanation before downgrade answer.